# MAMP 3 on a Mac with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, mamp

I am using MAMP version 3 on a Mac running OS 10.9.2. I installed Wordpress and created a site. Everything was working fine and I wanted to create another site using MAMP. I did that and it worked fine. But when I went to the original site the dashboard doesn't show up. In MAMP when I was on site2 (the 2nd site) the original site didn't show up listed. I went into MAMP and made sure Apache was linked to my original site.The database is still there. Please help.

Dave

Comment: Using virtual hosts, for custom domain?

Comment: Perhaps [Superuser](http://superuser.com) would be better suited for this question...?

Answer (score 0):

in mamp, wamp or xampp there always the htdocs folder where you can replicate the wordpress  folder, for example wordpress1 or wordpress2 to create multiple wordpress instances. after that make sure they're both using separate dbs; as a result you'll have 2 instances of wordpress in xampp without any confusion.

apache shouldn't be an issue. you also don't need to configure apache virtualhost; to keep things simple everything under /htdocs is what apache servers when your pull up wordpress1 or wordpress2 instances.